# php if include _get else display an error

Tags: php

I am somewhat a newby at PHP ... so what im trying to do is to get the the page using the following code

```
<?php include $_GET['topic']; ?>
```

to get the url like this http://ulixtxteditor.org/entities/helpCentre?topic=credits
that much works great for me however if no page is found i would like to use the else statement to display an error instead of a blank page. What should I do? ex: http://ulixtxteditor.org/entities/helpCentre?topic=  so this part would display an error?

```
<?php if(isset){include $_GET['topic'];} else {echo "error"} ?>
```

I tried this but it wont work.

Comment: how does your given example work? It doesn't have a file type

Comment: "i would like to use the else statement".  So what's stopping you? There's no attempt at if/else logic here.

Comment: This also won't work with paths very well etc, this is just not a good way to do it. Are you trying to do a MVC layout? This is the wrong way

Comment: require or require_once in a try/catch block

Comment: i changed the urls to ones of my own websites for a working example of what i am asking for

Comment: None of this answers my questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use something like this:

```
<?php
// In case topic parameter wasn't provided you will have fallback.
$topic = isset($_GET['topic']) ? $_GET['topic'] : '';
// Now you can check topic and have valid file name.
switch ($topic) {
    case 'credits':
        $fileName = 'credits.php';
        break;
    default:
        $fileName = 'index.php';
        break;
}
// Now it is possible safely include file.
include __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileName;
```

Using `$_GET['topic']` directly in `include` or `require` construction is unsafe because you vulnerable to "Directory traversal attack". Moreover you always must validate input parameters with purpose avoid include in php script css files etc...

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php include $_GET['topic']; ?>
```

**Don't do that.** It creates a massive and easily-exploited security vulnerability.

For example:

- `?topic=index.php` -- creates an infinite loop
- `?topic=/etc/passwd` -- displays sensitive data from the server
- `?topic=/proc/self/environ` -- executes code from the process environment. This will frequently include user-controlled data like the values of HTTP headers, allowing for remote code execution.

Your site *will* be exploited if you implement this. There are numerous bots which scan public web sites for this vulnerability, many of which will attempt to exploit it automatically upon detection.

If you want to include a file based on the value of a GET variable, use `switch($_GET['topic')` to define the acceptable values of that variable. This will also allow you to implement error handling as a `default:` clause.

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly common way of implementing a simple junction box/router.  Use a switch statement.

```
$topic = isset($_GET['topic']) ? $_GET['topic'] : '';
switch ($page) {
    case 'credit':
    case 'otherpage':
    case 'otherpage2':
      require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/' . $page . '.php');
      break;
    default
      require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/' . 'default.php');    
}
```

You whitelist your pages/topics by adding a case statement at the top for each, and anything that doesn't match or have a page is processed by loading the default page.

In this example, I assume all the topic pages are in the same directory as this script (typically named index.php).